# How to use antmedia server webrtc_adaptor in my angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, ant-media-server-sdk

When I implemented it, it was unable to find WebRTC adaptor from `node_modules/antmedia/webrtc_adaptor.js` so I created a folder in `node_modules/@types` named by `webrtc_adaptor` in which I added `index.d.ts` and paste the code in that file:

```
declare module '@antmedia/webrtc_adaptor'
```

So it was able to get webrtc adaptor, but it's giving following error:

> ./node_modules/@antmedia/webrtc_adaptor/index.html:1:0 - Error: Module
> parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate
> loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured
> to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Please tell me how to resolve it.